# Prove that a given matrix representation of a linear operator is, in fact, a representation

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, representation-theory

I'm starting to learn about representation theory of groups, and I'm having trouble coming up with a technical proof. Here's the setup and the notation I'm using:

Let $g$ be an element of a group $G$. Given a vector space $V,$ let $T(g) \in Aut(V)$ be the linear operator assigned to $g$. But, this $T(g)$ is general, i.e. not assigned to a specific basis. Then, let $D(g)$ be the matrix representation of $T(g)$ with a particular basis.

Now, we define the matrix elements of $D(g)$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
T(g)e_i=e_kD(g)^k_i \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)
\end{equation}
where $k$ is the row index, $i$ is the column index, $e_k$ are the basis vectors, and summation over $k$ is implied. Note that $e_k$ is a row vector, if that maters.

Now, I must show that $D$ is in fact a representation, by showing

(1) $D(E)=I$ (the identity $E \in G$ maps to the identity matrix) and

(2) $D(g_1g_2)=D(g_1)D(g_2)$.

I think I have (1) mostly correct:
\begin{equation}
T(E)e_i=e_kD(E)^k_i \\
e_i=e_kD(E)^k_i
\end{equation}
and since $e_i$ is a basis vector, it cannot be written as a linear combination of any of the other basis vectors. Thus $D(E)^k_i=0$ for $i \neq k$ and $D(E)^i_i=1$. Thus $D(E)=I$.

For part (2), I am struggling — especially with implied summations and indices flying around. Here is what I have so far:
\begin{equation}
T(g_1g_2)e_i=e_kD(g_1g_2)^k_i \\
T(g_1)T(g_2)e_i=e_kD(g_1g_2)^k_i \\
T(g_1)e_kD(g_2)^k_i=e_kD(g_1g_2)^k_i
\end{equation}

Now I have summations over $k$ implied on both sides. I want to perhaps apply definition $(*)$ to $T(g_1)e_k$ on the left hand side, but I am unsure about how to handle the summation over $k$ if I do so. Any suggestions? Or another approach entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a group $G$, a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb F$ and a *group homomorphism* $T\colon G\to \mathrm{Aut}(V)$. This setup guarantees us that $T(g_1g_2)=T(g_1)\circ T(g_2)$ and $T(e)=\mathrm{id}_V$.

Now we pick a particular basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ of $V$, in other words we have a linear isomorphism $\varphi\colon V\to \mathbb{F}^n$. This allows us to define:

$$D\colon G\to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb F^n),~D(g) = \varphi\circ T(g)\circ \varphi^{-1}$$

It is clear that each $D(g)$ is an automorphism (it's a composition of isomorphisms) and that $D$ is a group homomorphism:

$$D(g_1)\circ D(g_2) = (\varphi \circ T(g_1) \circ \varphi^{-1}) \circ (\varphi \circ T(g_2) \circ \varphi^{-1}) = \varphi \circ T(g_1g_2) \circ \varphi^{-1} = D(g_1g_2)$$

(We don't need to check that it preserves the identity, this is automatic from elementary group theory).

Edit: I put the construction in a more explicit way.

Take a linear map $f\colon V\to V$. A vector $f(v_i)$ can be uniquely written in terms of basis as:
$$f(v_i) = a_i^1 v_1 + \dots + a_i^n v_n$$
We gather these $a_i^j$ numbers into a matrix. (This is what basically the map $\varphi$ does in the definition of $D(g)$).

This assignment has the following properties:

- the map $\mathrm{id}_V$ is represented by the identity matrix $I_n$,
- the map $f\circ g$ is represented by the product of matrices $a^i_jb^j_k$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I understand the way you're showing $D$ is a homomorphism here, but I'm afraid I don't see the connection between the $D$ you are using and the $D$ that is being explicitly constructed in the definition I've been given. Are they related, or is something else going on here?

Comment: The method above takes a linear map $T(g)$ and returns a matrix $D(g)$, such that you immediately see that the matrices form a representation.
Your definition of $D(g)$ is just more explicit (in terms of basis vectors, not an isomorphism).

Comment: Ah, ok. As I'm trying to explicitly work with the definition I've been given (and I could use the practice with index gymnastics — this is for a physics course), is there a way to finish the proof that relates directly to this specific $D$?